# How to stop combination "command+tab" key while running the script

Tags: applescript

I’m using “Keystroke” to fill the UI with the assigned variable, but when I switch to another application the script continues to apply the keystroke.

I'm using the below code to make the application active again, but is there a possibility to stop the combination key until the script gets completed

```
on ActiveError()

global frontApp, frontAppName, windowTitle

set windowTitle to ""
tell application "System Events"
    set frontApp to first application process whose frontmost is true
    set frontAppName to name of frontApp
    tell process frontAppName
        tell (1st window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true)
            set windowTitle to value of attribute "AXTitle"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

if frontAppName is not equal to "Adobe InDesign 2022" then
    
    tell application "Adobe InDesign 2022" to activate
    
    -CustomAlert()
    
end if

return {frontAppName, windowTitle}

end ActiveError
```

Thank you

Comment: One possibility would be to register for NSWorkspace notifications so that your app is notified when the Finder is about to activate an app.  How are you applying the keystrokes?

Comment: @red_menace Thank you for the information, I don't want to get notified but I want to stay focused on the application until the background script finished

Keystrokes I'm doing it directly

(*tell application "Adobe InDesign 2022" to activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke tab
tell application "Adobe InDesign 2022" to activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke tab*)

Comment: Any scripting of the UI, such as keystrokes, only targets the currently active app, it doesn’t work in the background.